# Repeater FooterTemplate Button Click Event Not being handled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When debugging, clicking on btnSignup does not hit the breakpoint on the first line of my btnSignup_Click event.

Just to see if it'd help I removed the datasourceID from the repater and created a Sub routine to databind the repeater on page_load if-not-isPostback.  That didn't help.

What do I need to do to get my btnSignup to fire my btnSignup_Click event?

I have this on my ASCX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptParticipants" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsParticipants">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p class="participant"><span class="participant-number"><%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>.</span> <span class="participant-name"><%# Container.DataItem("name")%></span></p>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <br />            
            <asp:Literal ID="litBlanks" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <div class="text-center">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSignup" runat="server" Text="Sign Me Up" CssClass="btnSignup" OnClick="btnSignup_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove Me" CssClass="btnRemove" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" />
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

I have this on my ASCX.vb

```
Public Sub btnSignup_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        CheckAvailability() 'Breakpoint on this line
        'more code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to confirm, do you have any handlers for Repeater events? Like for Command event for example?

Comment: Also, do you manipulate the repeater anyhow? Like change visibility, or rebind it every post back, or something like that?

Comment: Andrei no to repeater events.  Do I manipulate the repeater?  Not on purpose.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but my rptParticipants is on an ASCX that is loaded inside a panel that is inside an itemtemplate of a parent repeater.

Comment: One more thing...when you click btnSignup the page postsback and the parent panel mentioned in the previous comment is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ItemCommand Event on the Repeater to handle your button clicks.  Replace the OnClick Attribute with the CommandName as shown below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSignup" runat="server" Text="Sign Me Up" CssClass="btnSignup" CommandName="SignUp" />
```

Next, create an event handler for your Repeater's ItemCommand Event:

```
Protected Sub rptParticipants_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles rptParticipants.ItemCommand

    If e.CommandName = "SignUp" Then

        btnSignup_Click(Me, New System.EventArgs)

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: NoAlias thanks for the suggestion.  It was a good idea. Unfortunately that did not work.